# A question about a finite abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group such that $x = \prod_{g \in G} g$

Let $H = \{h \in G: h^2 = 1\}$.

Show that $x= \prod_{h \in H} h$.

I know since $G$ is abelian, the order in which we multiply the elements doesn't matter. I think multiplicative inverse must be used. I start by choosing an arbitrary element in $G$, and prove that it is in $H$?

Comment: @sylvia, well edited!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti oh thank you! :)

Comment: @sylvia thank you! i am new to website

Comment: @Brandon, welcome to MSE! As you have seen, $\LaTeX$ is the language of choice for writing Maths here. Please review carefully the editing sylvia has done for you, so next time you can write directly in $\LaTeX$, making it so much easier for people to read. And note how sylvia made the body of the problems self-contained, independently of the title.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization.

Answer (score 2):

Elements of $H$ are those such that $g=g^{-1}$ because $g^2=1$ is equivalent to $g=g^{-1}$.

Therefore, if $g$ is not in $H$ then $g^{-1}$ is different from $g$, and
in the global product $$x=\prod_{g\in G} g$$ such an element cancels with its inverse.
Thus in $x$ only the elements of $H$ survive.

Comment: So we are proving x, the product of all elements of G, is equivalent to the elements of H. Would i need to prove it the other way as well? Why do we suppose g is not in H, this seems like a proof by contradiction.

Comment: we proved that the product of all elements of G equals the product of all element of H because elements that are not in H cancel with their inverse. For every g in G either g is in H or not. If not, it cancels.

Answer (score 0):

An idea: pair up (when possible) every element in the group with its inverse. What elements cannot be paired up?  Precisely those that fulfill $\;g^2=1\iff g^{-1}=g\;$ .

One of these elements if the group's unit. Now, check two cases: when there are elements of order two (involutions) in $\;G\;$ and when there are not.

For example, if there aren't then $\;g^2=1\iff g=1\;$ . But now do the multiplication defining $\;x\;$ putting every element in $\;G\;$ together with its inverse (when possible). What do you get?

Now you try the other case (you may want to know/prove that in this case the product of two involutions is again an involution...or the unit).